# Unusual Error in function passing map

Tags: c++, sfml

I don't quite understand the entirety of the situation that could have led to this, I made quite a large amount of changes to this function, but it seems that this isn't a function issue rather than an issue in the function *calling* this function.

```
main(){
    //set up variables...
    //theVector is made on the spot using a constructor
    Player thePlayer(proper, variables, here);
    Map theMap();
    theMap.functionThatAddsValues(stuff);
    std::map<ObjectName, Drawing> theMap;
    //This map is filled by using theMap[ObjectName::TheObject] since
    //this is mapped by its first values being enumerated data.
    movement(theVector, thePlayer, theMap, theDrawings);
    //other stuff
}

void movement(sf::Vector2f theVector, Player thePlayer, Map theMap, std::map<ObjectName, Drawing> theDrawings){
    //use the joyous variables
}
```

If this information is too vague, I can do a code dump link later of the file, I just think the code is too big to post here in its entirety since it has both functions and lines of codes that I plan on removing due to deprecation, and functions that aren't finished yet (as shown by the errors).

Edit: Forgot to mention the error:

```
/home/sir-lulzalot/Testland/sfml/SFMLink/main.cpp:277: error:
 undefined reference to `movement(sf::Vector2<float>, Player, Map, std::map<ObjectName,
 Drawing, std::less<ObjectName>, std::allocator<std::pair<ObjectName const, Drawing> > >)'
```

Edit2: Here's a dump of the main.cpp http://pastebin.com/TyCzWyfK

Edit3: Derp found answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a linker error.

You don't have consistent declarations and definitions.

This is the declaration of the movement function at the top of the file:

```
void movement(sf::Vector2f, Player, Map, std::map<ObjectName, Drawing>);
```

This is the definition of the movement function:

```
void movement(sf::Vector2f theVector, Player &thePlayer, Map &theMap, std::map<ObjectName, Drawing> theDrawings){
```

Notice that the definition takes a `Player&`, while the declaration says `Player`.

Comment: No, he does not define two variables called `theMap`. See my answer.

Comment: Fair enough, but I don't think thats the root of the problem, his code seems to be heavily copy-edited for the post, which seems to have introduced a lot of extra errors.

Comment: @JBentley Apologies. There's a prototype for void movement, so that's not the issue. I'll do a code dump for y'all in a sec.

Comment: @antiduh I've added a dump in case you want to take a look at the full main.cpp http://pastebin.com/TyCzWyfK

Comment: NEVER MIND THIS IS IT. I am not the smartest

Comment: I've said this a few times this week - as the french say, mise en place. This is a mistake you made because your workspace is a mess - the size of that file is huge. Break it up into smaller parts, individual files or classes etc.

Answer (score 3):

For a start, this line probably doesn't do what you think it does:

`Map theMap();`

This declares a parameter-less function named `theMap` which returns a `Map`. (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work) for the reason why). I'm guessing you probably intended to create a variable named `theMap` of type `Map`, in which case you need to remove the parentheses.

You then use the same name (`theMap`) for a variable of type `std::map<ObjectName, Drawing>`. I'm going to hazard another guess and say that you meant for this variable to be called `theDrawing`.

Beyond that, you haven't shown the code for variables `theVector` or `theDrawings`, so if you want more answers, I suggest you put together a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Or in other words, do not leave out any code which is necessary for generating the error.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/TyCzWyfK Here's a copy of the main file, I don't believe the other .hs/.cpps are required. But I can put them up at request.